# RegExpr and variable

Tags: javascript, regexp-replace

I have just one question maybe stupid (like every day)

```
var word = []; (an array with 100 words for example)
var tab = []; // resultat
var root = "test";
var debut = "Anti";
var reg1=new RegExp("^"+debut + "+." + root,"g")
    for(var i = 0;i<word.length; i++){ 
 // a word begin with Anti and contain test pls
        if (word[i].match(reg1)){´
            tab.push(word[i])
        }
}
    console.log(tab.join(', ');
```

but it is dont work, i dont know how to use variable with regexpr, thanks, sorry for my english

Comment: You want to get the words from the `word` array, that *start* with 'test' and also contain 'Anti', into the `tab` array?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how your code "doesn't work"? What were you expecting, and what actually happened? If you got an exception/error, post the line it occurred on and the exception/error details. Please [edit] these details in or we may not be able to help.

Comment: The regex would look like `/^Anti+.test/g`, did you try that directly, whithout the variables, and does it work then ?

Comment: `+.` should probably be `.+`.

Answer (score 0):

```js
var r = new RegExp('anti.*esis', 'ig')

document.write('antithesis'.match(r), '<br/>') // ["antithesis"]
document.write('antihero'.match(r), '<br/>') // null
```

Comment: Thanks Ben Aston !!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code, but is used the test() instead of match()

```
 var word=["yea","antiboyahtest","antigssjshbztest"];
var debut="anti";
var root="test";
var reg=new RegExp("^"+debut+".*"+root,"g");
var tabs=[];
for(i in word){
 if(reg.test(word[i])){
  tabs.push(word[i]);
 }
}
alert(tabs);
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution using `RegExp.test` and `Array.filter` functions:

```
var word = ['Antitest', 'Antidot', 'Anti-next-test', 'testAnti'],
    root = "test", debut = "Anti",
    reg1 = new RegExp("^"+debut + ".*?" + root, "g");

var result = word.filter(function (w) {
    return reg1.test(w);
});

console.log(result);  // ["Antitest", "Anti-next-test"]
```

Also, there's an additional approach using `Array.indexOf` function without any regex which will give the same result:

```
...
var result = word.filter(function (w) {
    return w.indexOf(debut) === 0 && w.indexOf(root) !== -1;
});
```